# Check interval between midnight of a certain date and current moment in JS / node /moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, momentjs

I have a JS Date object (such as `09.08.2020 15.45`) and would like to write an expression
"present moment is less than 3 minutes after midnight of next date" (so it is `true` for times from `09.09.2020 00:00` up until `09.09.2020 00:03` and otherwise false).

What would be an optimal, most elegant way to express it? I can use any npm package such as `moment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [`isBetween`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/).
It also is available in [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-between#docsNav)

```
function isLessThanThreeMinutesPastMidnight(date) {
  const nextMidnight = moment().add(1, 'days').startOf('day');
  const threeMinutesPastNextMidnight = moment(nextMidnight).add(3, 'minute');

  return moment(date).isBetween(nextMidnight, threeMinutesPastNextMidnight, null, '[)'); 
}
```

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jrdmfg)

If you find `null, '[)'` not very elegant you may consider using the end of today instead of the start of tomorrow:

```
function isLessThanThreeMinutesPastMidnight(date) {
  const now = moment.now(); // helps to avoid problems with changing the date between `now` calls
  const endOfDay = moment(now).endOf('day');
  const threeMinutesPastNextMidnight = moment(now).add(1, 'days').startOf('day').add(3, 'minute');

  return moment(date).isBetween(endOfDay, threeMinutesPastNextMidnight);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! works well. I only add a note that the moments are mutable. So if instead of moment(now) someone uses a pre-defined moment, then ```const threeMinutesPastNextMidnight = someMoment.add(1, 'days')``` WILL alter ```someMoment``` to also move 1 day forward,even if it is counter-intuitive. Thanks to @Edeph answer below for this note.

Comment: You're right, working with moment.js it is a good practice to wrap any date/moment into a moment call before use.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` from momentJS ([docs here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/)) in to compare your date with midnight date and midnight date plus 3 minutes.

Be careful according to [docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/00-intro/): `It should be noted that moments are mutable. Calling any of the manipulation methods will change the original moment.`

Example code:

```
const t1 = moment().add(2, 'minutes'); // one moment in time

setTimeout(() => {
    const now = moment();
    const threeMinutesOver = moment().add(3, 'minutes');

    console.log(t1.isAfter(now) && t1.isBefore(threeMinutesOver)); // t1 is between 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with pure JavaScript: Get midnight to next day by creating a new date with year, month and day from today and 24 hours. By this you even get the right day/time if it's a day with timechange from summer/wintertime independently the actual daytime.
Take the difference between testing-date and midnight and look if the result is between 0 and 180.000 ms.

```js
function chechMidnight3Minutes(date) {
  let today = new Date();
  let midnight = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate(),24);
  let diff = date.getMilliseconds() - midnight.getMilliseconds(); 
  diff = (date - midnight); 
  return diff>=0 && diff<=180000;
}

let date = new Date('2020-08-10T00:02:59');
console.log(chechMidnight3Minutes(date));

date = new Date('2020-08-10T00:03:00');
console.log(chechMidnight3Minutes(date));

date = new Date('2020-08-10T01:02:00');
console.log(chechMidnight3Minutes(date));

date = new Date('2020-08-0910T00:00:00');
console.log(chechMidnight3Minutes(date));

date = new Date('2020-08-0910T23:59:59');
console.log(chechMidnight3Minutes(date));
```